# JAX-WS: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 30))

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I have JAX-WS service and on the one method, which client is calling service throws exception:

```
    javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 30))
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,675176]]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:249)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:100)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:641)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:600)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:585)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:482)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:314)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:608)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:259)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:213)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:159)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:194)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 30))
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,675176]]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:435)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:371)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.BridgeImpl.unmarshal(BridgeImpl.java:124)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.api.Bridge.unmarshal(Bridge.java:237)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointArgumentsBuilder$RpcLit$PartBuilder.readRequest(EndpointArgumentsBuilder.java:680)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointArgumentsBuilder$RpcLit.readRequest(EndpointArgumentsBuilder.java:646)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:247)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 30))
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,675176]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwInvalidSpace(StreamScanner.java:666)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.readTextSecondary(BasicStreamReader.java:4638)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.finishToken(BasicStreamReader.java:3675)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.safeFinishToken(BasicStreamReader.java:3629)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.getTextCharacters(BasicStreamReader.java:857)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamReaderFilter.getTextCharacters(XMLStreamReaderFilter.java:144)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleCharacters(StAXStreamConnector.java:328)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:192)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:369)
        ... 35 more
```

I searched problem and it seemes that service uses enconding, which not supports some characters. Can I tell service to use some other encoding or there is some other way to solve this problem?

Thanks you!

Comment: your client is receiving binary data instead of the expected xml soap response. the binary data may be due to soap compression or encryption.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I edit my message before return?

Comment: It's important to note that this might *not* be an encoding issue at all. It may well be that the client is just providing an invalid XML file which *does* include Unicode U+002E (decimal 30). They should simply stop doing so.